# Missing context JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a method `_addEvents` that sets click event for buttons using JQuery `on.` function. This also gives id of clicked button for `cartCollection.removeItem(buttonId);` Problem is that its keeps loosing id value of button and gives `undefined`

**EDITED**
`_addEvents` must get id of clicked button from this template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="cartTemplate">
<ul id = "cartList" >
    <% for(var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++){%>
    <%if(data.items[i].quantity === 1){%>
    <li><%=data.items[i].item.id%><br>
        <%=data.items[i].item.name%><br>
        Price per Phone:<%=data.items[i].item.price%><br>
        <%=data.items[i].thisItemTotal %><br>
        Total Quantity:<%=data.TotalQuantity%><br>
        Total Price:<%=data.total%><br>
        <button id="<%=data.items[i].item.id%>" type="button" class="removeButton btn btn-default" aria-label="center-align">
            Remove
        </button>
    </li>
    <%} else {%>
    <li><%=data.items[i].item.id%><br>
        <%=data.items[i].item.name%><br>
        Quantity:<%=data.items[i].quantity%><br>
        Price per Phone:<%=data.items[i].item.price%><br>
        <%=data.items[i].thisItemTotal %><br>
        Total Quantity:<%=data.TotalQuantity%><br>
        Total Price:<%=data.total%><br>
        <button id="<%=data.items[i].item.id%>" type="button" class="removeButton btn btn-default" aria-label="center-align">
            Remove
        </button>
    </li>
    <%}%>
    <%}%>
</ul>
</script>
```

Realization of `_addEvents` and object that this method belongs to:

```
var cartList = {
    _itemsCollections: cartCollection,
    _template: _.template($('#cartTemplate').html()),
    _rootElement: $('#ordersCartDiv'),
    //_rootElementUl: $("#cartList"),
    initialize: function () {
        'use strict';
        //this.divId = divId;
        //this._rootElementUl = $("#cartList");
        //this._itemsCollections= cartCollection;
        //bind(this._addEvents(),cartList);
        this._addEvents();
    },
    render: function () {
        'use strict';
        var data = {
            items: this._itemsCollections.getItems(),
            total: this._itemsCollections.getTotalPrice(),
            TotalQuantity: this._itemsCollections.getTotalQuantity()
        };
        var rendTemplate = this._template({data: data});
        this._rootElement.html(rendTemplate);
        this._addEvents();
        console.log(this._itemsCollections);
    },
    _addEvents: function () {
        'use strict';
        var self = this;
        this._rootElement.on('click','.removeButton' , function () {
            var buttonId = $(self).attr('id'); // undefined
            console.log('id:' + buttonId);
            cartCollection.removeItem(buttonId);
            cartList.render();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, this should give you the id of the clicked button. What is not working? How does it "*keep loosing id value of button*"? What id do you expect it to be?

Comment: Much clearer now, thanks, see below my edited suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OKAY - your `this` refers to the callback context, you should get the clicked object from the event object:

```
_addEvents: function () {
    'use strict';
    this._rootElement.on('click','.removeButton' , function ( e ) {
        var buttonId = $( e.currentTarget ).attr('id'); // GET TARGET FROM EVENT
        console.log('id:' + buttonId);
        cartCollection.removeItem(buttonId);
        cartList.render();
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, now instead of nothing it gives me: `id:undefined`.

Comment: Then your _addEvent_ is not bound to the root element, _you have to make this clear in your question!_ So lets put it this way, you should save the context in the context where you define the callback, I'm editing accordingly.